# How can I insert html Code in Typo3 8.7 Form extension in a label or description Field

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I want insert this code in a Label or Description Field of a Contact-Form Field:

```
test <a href="/index.php?id=4">Page</a>
```

But when I save the form, the HTML-Code was removed:

```
test Page
```

How can I deactivate the removing of HTML Code in Typo3 8.7 tx_form?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TYPO3 v8, EXT:form does not provide this out-of-the-box. You can use a custom form element to achieve this. Here is an example: https://github.com/tritum/form_element_linked_checkbox

The upcoming TYPO3 v9 *could* contain a slim configuration for the CKEditor RTE to the form labels. It would allow to add links or style texts. The agency TRITUM worked on this as part of the TYPO3 User Experience Week 2018 (T3UXW18). It has yet to be added to the core, though.

Source: https://twitter.com/tritum/status/988778861948174336

Comment: Correct, we remove all HTML entered in the form editor. Anyway, you could try to alter the fluid templates to achieve your goal. Or, as suggested, you could use our extension. We are TRITUM by the way ;)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but It's not able to have a link for only a part of the label with your extension. Any suggestion how to do this.
Otherwise I'm considering to write a custom HTML element if it's not that struggle.

Comment: The latest TYPO3 and EXT.form 9.5.13 doesn't contain this important feature. That's really sad. In times of "EU-DSGVO/GDPR" it's too bad. Unfortunately back again to EXT:powermail.